# How to check for no data select in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a query to select some data in a function but after if I am not getting data from it I need run a different query.
How I am doing it right now is:

```
SELECT 1 INTO flag
          FROM   "schema"."table"
          WHERE col1 = variable
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
if(flag = 1) then
  SELECT    "col1"                                             
            INTO    col1_2
            FROM    "schema"."table"                                                
          WHERE col1 = variable;
end if;
```

But this is making my function too complicated as I have to run this part many times as I have many such conditions and query.

Is there any way I can use sqlcode as I know sqlcode for successful run of query which is returning No rows is 100. Something like this:

```
SELECT    "col1"                                             
                INTO    col1_2
                FROM    "schema"."table"                                                
              WHERE col1 = variable;
if(SQLCODE=100)
   --run next set of queries
end if;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the special variable `FOUND`:

```
SELECT ... INTO col1_2 ...
IF NOT FOUND THEN
   ...
END IF;
```

Alternatively, you can rely on the fact that the variable will be `NULL` if the query returned no row:

```
SELECT .. INTO col1_2 ...
IF col1_2 IS NULL THEN
   ...
END IF;
```

The second method is not as good; it will only work if the value returned cannot be a null value.